How to write a custom Google Sheets Conditional Formatting rule based on multiple criteria?
I have a simplified scheduling sheet that contains a list of employees who are scheduled to work in specific areas and the dates they are scheduled for.  The sheet also includes an "Unavailability Tracker" where I list the employees who have called out on those dates.  I would like the sheet to highlight any employees who are scheduled to work on a date when they called out.
The conditional formatting rule should:

Find the date in column A
Match the date to the date in a column header in range F2:H2
Highlight the names of any employees to the corresponding sections in columns B:D who cannot work on the days they are scheduled.

I have manually highlighted the cells in red that I would like the conditional formatting to automatically highlight because they are scheduled on days when they cannot work.  I would like it to work with partial text from the cells in F3:H10 and work if there are multiple schedules for the same date.  Thank you!
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Fnbs_Nx41oF2MMjD5kzOjRTUdSVUL6EsHxXZVDAMhGI/edit#gid=0
I have tried MANY variations of the following formula.  Which almost works but it doesn't pickup the names that correspond to the correct date column in F2:H2.
=AND($A$2=TRANSPOSE($F$2:$H$2), ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IFERROR(LEN($F$3:$F$10)*SEARCH($F$3:$F$10,B3)))) > 0)

You can use the following conditional formatting custom formula applied to B3:D.
=REGEXMATCH(B3,"(?i)"&TEXTJOIN("|",1,INDEX($F$3:$H$10,,XMATCH(CHOOSEROWS(FILTER($A$2:$A3,$A$2:$A3),-1),$F$2:$H$2))))

Or with open ranges:
=REGEXMATCH(B3,"(?i)"&TEXTJOIN("|",1,INDEX($F$3:$ZZZ,,XMATCH(CHOOSEROWS(FILTER($A$2:$A3,$A$2:$A3),-1),$F$2:$2))))

